# Need to get the output only when the loop ends

Tags: c

Here, i want to get the output only after the user enters the letter 'Q', which is the last task of my program. However, when i enter 'R' which is another case for my program, it directly prints the output for me.

```
int main() {

    float amountOfTurkishLira = 0;
    float amountOfBtc = 0;
    float amountOfEth = 0;
    char operationCode;

    char operationTurkishLira;

    // getting the amount of money for the initial money;
    scanf(" %c", &operationTurkishLira);
    if (operationTurkishLira != 'T') {
        printf("Error: Operation could not be completed.");
    } else {

        scanf(" %f", &amountOfTurkishLira);
        scanf(" %c", &operationCode);

        while (operationCode != 'Q') {
            switch (operationCode) {
                case 'R':
                    if (amountOfBtc == 0 && amountOfEth == 0) {
                        printf("Our account holds %.2f TRY", amountOfTurkishLira);
                    } else {
                        printf("Our account holds %.2f TRY | %.2f BTC | %.2F ETH.", amountOfTurkishLira, amountOfBtc,
                               amountOfEth);
                    }
                    scanf(" %c", &operationCode);
                    break;
            }
        }
        printf("Bye..");

    }


    return 0;
}
```

This happens when i enter the input:

```
T
1000
R
Our account holds 1000.00 TRY
Bye...
```

But I want it to be like this:

```
T 
1000
R
Q
```

after i enter all my input, it should give me

```
Our account holds 1000.00 TRY 
Bye...
```

Comment: If you don't want it to be done in the loop, move the printing code down to after the loop is done.

Comment: What's confusing about that?

Comment: Also, the `scanf()` shouldn't be inside `switch/case`.

Answer (score 0):

Take the printing code out of the loop and do it at the end.

And take `scanf(" %c", &operationCode);` out of the `switch`, since it should be done no matter what the previous code was.

```
int main() {

    float amountOfTurkishLira = 0;
    float amountOfBtc = 0;
    float amountOfEth = 0;
    char operationCode;

    char operationTurkishLira;

    // getting the amount of money for the initial money;
    scanf(" %c", &operationTurkishLira);
    if (operationTurkishLira != 'T') {
        printf("Error: Operation could not be completed.");
    } else {

        scanf(" %f", &amountOfTurkishLira);
        scanf(" %c", &operationCode);

        while (operationCode != 'Q') {
            switch (operationCode) {
            case 'R':
                break;
            }
            scanf(" %c", &operationCode);
        }
        if (amountOfBtc == 0 && amountOfEth == 0) {
            printf("Our account holds %.2f TRY", amountOfTurkishLira);
        } else {
            printf("Our account holds %.2f TRY | %.2f BTC | %.2F ETH.", amountOfTurkishLira, amountOfBtc,
                   amountOfEth);
        }
        printf("Bye..");

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on my version. I have some comments in it. You just have to add your logic for the case you pressing 'R' or an other key (I suppose you will add some more key press listeners).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    float amountOfTurkishLira = 0;
    float amountOfBtc = 0;
    float amountOfEth = 0;
    char operationCode;
    char operationTurkishLira;

    // getting the amount of money for the initial money;
    scanf(" %c", &operationTurkishLira);
    if (operationTurkishLira != 'T') {
        printf("Error: Operation could not be completed.");
    } 
    else {
        scanf(" %f", &amountOfTurkishLira);
        scanf(" %c", &operationCode);

        while (operationCode != 'Q') {
            switch (operationCode) {
                case 'R':
                    if (amountOfBtc == 0 && amountOfEth == 0) {
                        printf("LOGIC FOR amountOfBtc == 0 && amountOfEth == 0\n");
                    } else {
                        printf("LOGIC FOR amountOfBtc != 0 || amountOfEth != 0\n");
                    }
                    break;
                case 'X': // X, Y, or WHATEVER
                    // LOGIC FOR 'X'
                    break;
            }

            scanf(" %c", &operationCode);
        }
        if (operationCode == 'Q') {
            if (amountOfBtc == 0 && amountOfEth == 0) {
                printf("Our account holds %.2f TRY\n", amountOfTurkishLira);
            } 
            else {
                printf("Our account holds %.2f TRY | %.2f BTC | %.2F ETH.\n", amountOfTurkishLira, amountOfBtc, amountOfEth);
            }
            printf("Bye..");
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```